Stopping worker nodes using prometheus-am-executor
Assume that I have several nodes which I am monitoring using Prometheus. I wish to stop (or shutdown, im not really sure what the correct term to use would be) a node based on GPU metrics I get (gpu hours, utilization etc). Would it be possible to do so using prometheus-am-executor? if yes, how so? maybe there is a simpler solution im not aware of? would robusta be better instead of prometheus-am-executor?
